# Using a regex to append to the end of non-blank lines

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I would think that this would be a common question, but I can't find anybody asking how to do this. There are people asking how to do the opposite (find blank lines) and add a `<br><br>` at the end of each one. For human readability, this document has blank lines between paragraphs.

(I don't want to replace the blank lines with `<br><br>`. I know this would achieve the same result, but for human readability and personal preference, I don't like how this makes the document one giant block of text.)

How can I write a regex that captures -- I don't know if this is the right word to use; maybe "groups"? -- the end of lines that aren't blank so that I can append to the end of them?

I am using Visual Studio code, so I'd like this to work in the search/replace box:

[image]

I'm assuming in the replacement box above, I'd need to say `$some group number(s?)`, so I just said `$x` as a temporary placeholder. Here's what I've tried as search patterns:

```
^(?!:($))$
^(?!:(\S$))$
^(?!:([^\S]$))$
^(?!:([^\s]$))$
^(?!([^\S]+))$
```

All of these seem to grab the inverse of what I'm trying to find. I guess my strategy has been, between the beginning and end of the line, there shouldn't be only whitespace. But I'm pretty sure that's not what I'm saying.

Comment: What if the lines end with trailing spaces? Do you want to remove them?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's a good question I hadn't thought about. Removing trailing white space wouldn't be necessary for me to accept an answer, but I'd still be curious and seeing how to do it both ways if someone wants to put in the effort.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex didn't have `^`...`$` around it, which I failed to notice. Yeah that'll work.

Comment: if I read your question correct you want: `lines that aren't blank` and that are `lines that are only white space or nothing`, they don't exist

Comment: @rioV8 hmm, I'm not sure where I'm saying the latter. I want what's in the title.

Comment: 2 paragraphs above the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

*Find What*:      `(\S)[^\S\n]*(\n)`
*Replace With*: `$1<br><br>$2`

**NOTE**: The above replacement will not add the `<br>`s at the end of the last line if it is not blank. If you need that, use

*Find What*:      `(\S)[^\S\n]*$`
*Replace With*: `$1<br><br>`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CzDhE/2). The regex above matches the last non-whitespace char on a line (capturing it in Group 1 to keep it), then matches horizontal whitespace (if any) and then captures a line break that is also captured to keep in the output.

*Details*

- `(\S)` - Group 1: any non-whitespace char
- `[^\S\n]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `(\n)` - Group 2: line break.
- `$` - end of a line (note that `m` flag (in its PCRE meaning) is always on, by default, in VSCode regex).

The replacement is `$1<br><br>$2`, Group 1 value + `<br><br>` + Group 2 value (if you use the first regex).

[image]

is changed into

[image]

Comment: Looks like this works, thanks! Can you explain why you needed to include the `\n`s in the regex? I get that it's saying "don't span beyond the line," and "go from non-whitespace to the end of the line," respectively, but why do you need to do that? Does VS code have the `.../m` flag on? Either way, I would have expected that `$` could be used in this regex. Why can't it be?

Comment: @DanielKaplan  `\n` matches any line break (sequence) in VSCode regex. I thought it would make no sense to add line breaks at the end of the file, hence used it instead of `(\S)[^\S\n]*$` -> `$1<br><br>`, which is also possible (but it will also add `<br>`s at the end of the last line if it is not blank. `/m` flag is implied in VSCode regex (it is always on, `^` matches start of a line and `$` matches end of a line).

Answer (score 1):

This works to retain the spaces at the end of lines:

Find:  `(?<=^.*)(\S+.*)`

Replace: `$1<br><br>`

[image]